# Javascript Cash Register - Why can't I log the total values of denominations

Tags: javascript

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
var register = [
["ONE HUNDRED", 100, cid[8][1]],
["TWENTY", 20, cid[7][1]], 
["TEN", 10, cid[6][1]], 
["FIVE", 5,  cid[5][1]],
["ONE", 1, cid[4][1]], 
["QUARTER", 0.25, cid[3][1]], 
["DIME", 0.10, cid[2][1]], 
["NICKEL", 0.05, cid[1][1]],
["PENNY", 0.01, cid[0][1]] 
]

var insuf = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
var closed = "CLOSED";
var open = "OPEN";
var totalRegister = register.reduce((sum, i) => sum + i[2], 0).toFixed(2);
var answer = {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []};
var change = Math.abs(price - cash);
var newArr = []
var count = 0


if (totalRegister == change) {
answer.status = closed;
answer.change = cid;
} else if (totalRegister < change) {
answer.status = insuf
} else if (totalRegister > change) {
for (var i of register) {
  while (change >= i[1] && i[2] > 0) {
    change = Math.round(change*100)/100;
    change -= i[1];
    i[2] -= i[1];
    var subArr = []
    subArr.push(i[0], i[1]);
    }
    if (subArr) {
      newArr.push(subArr)
    }
   }
  }
  console.log(newArr)
return answer
}
```

So my code above almost gets me to where I need to be and will log the below to the console;

```
[ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'ONE', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ]
```

With this as an input;

```
console.log(checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]));
```

IT logs the denomination of the currency I'm dealing with but I need to create a sum of how many times I've used that denomination. The rest of my code words as I need it to and I'll be able to work out if I can give the change necessary and then change the answer keys. It also logs the dime value twice and I cant work out why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `console.log(0.10+0.70);`, before you continue.

Comment: @StackSlave, that may or may not be relevant depending on requirements. `console.log((0.1+0.7).toFixed(2));` can be used to *fix* the issue with precision.

Comment: Thanks guys, but whereabouts in the code does this help? for the issue with the repeated dime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that in `subArr.push(i[0], i[1]);` you're pushing the value of the currency with `i[1]`, what you need is to find if that currency denomination already exists, and increment it's count. You could use the map data structure for that purpose, like so:

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var register = [
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100, cid[8][1]],
    ["TWENTY", 20, cid[7][1]],
    ["TEN", 10, cid[6][1]],
    ["FIVE", 5, cid[5][1]],
    ["ONE", 1, cid[4][1]],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25, cid[3][1]],
    ["DIME", 0.1, cid[2][1]],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05, cid[1][1]],
    ["PENNY", 0.01, cid[0][1]],
  ];

  var insuf = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
  var closed = "CLOSED";
  var open = "OPEN";
  var totalRegister = register.reduce((sum, i) => sum + i[2], 0).toFixed(2);
  var answer = {
    status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
    change: []
  };
  var change = Math.abs(price - cash);
  var newArr = [];
  var map = new Map();
  var count = 0;

  if (totalRegister == change) {
    answer.status = closed;
    answer.change = cid;
  } else if (totalRegister < change) {
    answer.status = insuf;
  } else if (totalRegister > change) {
    for (var i of register) {
      while (change >= i[1] && i[2] > 0) {
        change = Math.round(change * 100) / 100;
        change -= i[1];
        i[2] -= i[1];
        if (map.get(i[0])) {
          map.set(i[0], map.get(i[0]) + 1);
        } else {
          map.set(i[0], 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  newArr = [...map]
  console.log(newArr);
  return answer;
}

console.log(
  checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
    ["PENNY", 1.01],
    ["NICKEL", 2.05],
    ["DIME", 3.1],
    ["QUARTER", 4.25],
    ["ONE", 90],
    ["FIVE", 55],
    ["TEN", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 60],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
  ])
);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! all I had to do was change the count variable (i[1]) that set in the else statement to the denomination value from the first array, and change the incrementer in the if statement to (+i[1]) to keep adding the value of the denomination on each pass. Thanks!

Comment: Great that this helped! @JanQuadrantVincent, if this answered your question, please consider accepting this answer so the post gets resolved. Thank you!